# cannot rebind M-p

Tags: key-bindings, scrolling

I try to customize the scrolling experience within Emacs and for that rebound `M-n` and `M-p` to a new functionality, namely

```
(global-set-key "\M-n" "\C-u20\C-v")
(global-set-key "\M-p" "\C-u20\M-v")
```

and while it works for M-n, M-p does not work. If I reassign the function to e.g. M-o it also works as expected. Only M-p is refusing to work although there is no functionality overwriting it later in my config file.

Can anyone help please?

running yields for M-n

> M-n runs the command "20" (found in global-map), which is a keyboard macro. It is bound to M-n.
>   Macro: C-u 20 C-v Keyboard macro.

if I try the same for M-p there is no reaction i.e. any diagnosis, just nothing happens. I tried the same in emacs -q with the same result. But C-p and the like work oO

Comment: It works as expected for me. After you make the bindings, what does `C-h k M-p` report?

Comment: That's strange. What happens when you call `C-h k M-p` when you start Emacs (i.e., before you try your new keybindings)?

Comment: the same: nothing. for M-n it correctly shows: not defined and for M-p it does not react Oo

Comment: 1st: Can you reproduce the effect with `emacs -Q`?  2nd: `M-p` could be captured by a keymap of the operating system. (e.g., `xmodmap`).

Comment: I did in emacs -Q. I did fiffle with xmodmap in the past few days, I just recall. I dont seem to have a xmodmap file in my home directory. Where can I check if I set that somewhere?

Comment: I found it. Was overwritten in my awersome wm config file. thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was due to a problem entirely outside Emacs, and once this problem solved, no question about Emacs remains.